# Unable to write to subfolder in website

Tags: windows, permissions, iis-7.5

I have a webservice that I need to be able to write some logs for. The service is installed in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\myservice. The log files should be written to c:\inetpub\wwwroot\myservice\logging.
When I try running it in debug mode in Visual Studio, log files are created successfully. When I publish the site and try it, log files are not created.
I have tried giving write access for the logging folder to: NETWORK Service, IUSR, IIS_IUSRS, DefaultAppPool, ASP .NET 4.0 Classic but it made no difference. I also added Everyone with Full Control, but it made no difference.

Any ideas why I cannot get write access to this folder????

Comment: Did you grant permissions to the **ASPNET** user?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what caused the issue, but IIS had somehow got corrupted. It would no longer display pages either by using localhost or 127.0.0.1.

Removed and re-installed IIS, all working now.